# laravel не прекращать сеанс авторизации пользователя

Tags: laravel, сессия, auth

Здравствуйте, как в laravel 5.5 не прекращать сеанс авторизации пользователя. Т.е сейчас если не делать каких либо взаимодействий с приложением то нужно переавторизовываться. Хватит ли просто если увеличить SESSION_LIFETIME к примеру на месяц?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В session.php найдите

```
    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120, //по умолчанию - 120

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Тут как раз можно менять значения. Можно выставить месяц - 43200 минут.

Comment: Спасибо, буду тестировать. Просто сомневался правильно ли это.